# Can't transfer checkbox value to php code

Tags: php, checkbox

There is my old (15 years ago) webpage that is not working (though I remember it working back then), and I want to fix it. I would appreciate your help, it should be a really simple fix.

There is a form with checkboxes on a webpage with Get method, and when executed it should open php file that should get the data from url of the checked boxes and show the corresponding information. It seems like the problem is that php does not see these values for some reason.

html page:

```
<form action="/materials/materials_show.php" method="get" name="form1">
<label><input id="a100" name="a100" type="checkbox">Name1</label><br>
<label><input id="a101" name="a101" type="checkbox">Name2</label><br>
...
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

materials_show.php PHP code:

```
<?php
if ($a100==True) {include ("http://...");}
...
```

The resulting URL when first checkbox is checked is:
`http://mydomain/materials/materials_show.php?a100=on`

So the Get method seems working OK. Something wrong is with PHP code in materials_show.php.

I thought that it should be `if ($a100==on)` instead of `if ($a100==True)`, but it didn't help.

Comment: You get the GET variables (no pun intended) using `$_GET['variable_name']`

Comment: Where is `$a100` defined?  I vaguely recall years ago that PHP could be configured to automatically populate variables with form value names.  If you were relying on that then (1) updated PHP versions may disable it, and (2) don't rely on that.

Comment: `var_dump($a100, $_GET)` gives what?

Comment: The checkbox is only sent to the server if it's checked. So just use `if (isset($_GET['a100']))`. There's little point in testing the value.

Comment: @David It realy explains why it stopped working, i think you are right. It is not defined anywhere, the idea was that it comes from the form. I thought that variables can be defined in the url from that get method of the form thus php should already know them. Seems I have to use what Barmar suggests.

Answer (score 0):

First Of All You Should Use PHP [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) To Get Value Of Input
Like This :

```
  <?php
  $a100 = $_GET['a100'];
```